# All of a sudden java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.IOException without any changes made to the application

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror

I have a java jar which was compiled in 2015. The program has been working fine without any issues since recently. I keep getting the following error. There were no major changes made to the machine or the folder where the jar resides. What does it actually mean? I am missing java.io.ioexception? Can anyone explain why I would get this error when it has been working fine for a long time when I used the same script/cmd to run the jar. Our group has used the script for this task for years. I have posted error message below. Any hints would be appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.IOException
    at edu.msu.cme.rdp.alignment.hmm.jni.HMMER3.initHmmer(Native Method)
    at edu.msu.cme.rdp.alignment.hmm.jni.HMMER3.<init>(HMMER3.java:39)
    at edu.msu.cme.rdp.fungene.release.ReleasePipeline.main(ReleasePipeline.java:497)
```

Comment: a class has vanished from the classpath check with your admin what was changed in the system ;)

Comment: Did someone perhaps upgrade the Java Runtime?

Comment: I am the admin. There were no changes made to the system. Can someone tell what class is missing?

Comment: As already mentioned above: most likely JDK got updated and the path to it has changed. Verify the path and restart your application.

Comment: well **if** **you** didn't change anything you need to figure out who else did.

Comment: The jdk hasn't been updated. I am the only admin of the server.

Comment: I have checked the JDK path. It hasn't been updated for three years. And, I was the one who made that update.

Comment: honestly in that case: put the machine imidiately in quarantine until you know what happend. Most likely it will turn out harmless but from you description(you didn't change anything while something changed on the machine) it is to be considered compromised till proven otherwise. (maybe also check: reboot or similar may activate changes done in the past )

Comment: There is something *seriously* wrong with your Java installation. Repair or reinstall it.

Comment: I wrote a simple program with just line 497 from ReleasePipeline.java and compile the code using the same machine. I tested it and didn't have any issue. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: I found the issue. It was quite trivial. There was a format issue with the input file... :|